# JS Pointer Lock

Tags: javascript, pointerlock

I'm having trouble with pointer Locking. My code looks something like this...

```
Canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
...(Parameters)...
document.body.appendChild(Canvas);

Canvas.requestPointerLock = Canvas.requestPointerLock ||
             element.mozRequestPointerLock ||
             element.webkitRequestPointerLock;

Canvas.requestPointerLock();
```

When I run my code nothing happens with the pointer lock (everything else run noramly). The code i showed is just what i think is relevant to the issue but if more code from my program is needed just tell me.

Comment: `element.mozRequestPointerLock` etc should probably be `Canvas.mozRequestPointerLock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the WC3 Docs on `pointerlock`](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/#methods):

> `requestPointerLock`
>
> If a user has exited pointer lock via the default unlock user gesture, or pointer lock has not previously been entered for this document, an event generated as a result of an engagement gesture must be received by the document before `requestPointerLock` will succeed.

[It then talks about engagement gestures below.](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/#dfn-engagement-gesture)

> Engagement gesture
>
> An event generated by the user agent as a result of user interaction intended to interact with the page. e.g. `click`, but not `mousemove`. Engagement gestures are any events included in the definition of being allowed to show a popup with the addition of `keypress` and `keyup`.

So in order for your code to work, `requestPointerLock` should be called from an engagement gesture, for example a `click` event handler.

Answer (score 8):

If we move 'requestPointerLock()' inside click event, it works fine. Sharing below sample code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pointer lock</title>

<style type="text/css"> 
html {font-size: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;}
canvas {display: block; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
      <canvas width="640" height="360">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas
      </canvas>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// setup of the canvas

window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function eventWindowLoaded() {  
  canvasDraw();
}

var x = 50;
var y = 50;

function canvasDraw() { 
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.clientWidth,canvas.clientHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,degToRad(360), true);
  ctx.fill();
}

// pointer lock object forking for cross browser
canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock || canvas.mozRequestPointerLock;
document.exitPointerLock = document.exitPointerLock || document.mozExitPointerLock;

canvas.onclick = function() {
  canvas.requestPointerLock();
}

// pointer lock event listeners
// Hook pointer lock state change events for different browsers
document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);
document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);

function lockChangeAlert() {
  if(document.pointerLockElement === canvas ||
  document.mozPointerLockElement === canvas) {
    console.log('The pointer lock status is now locked');
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", canvasLoop, false);
  } else {
    console.log('The pointer lock status is now unlocked');  
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", canvasLoop, false);
  }
}


function canvasLoop(e) {
  var movementX = e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || 0;
  var movementY = e.movementY || e.mozMovementY ||  0;
  x += movementX;
  y += movementY; 
  canvasDraw();
  console.log("X position: " + x + ', Y position: ' + y);
}

// helper function
function degToRad(degrees) {
  var result = Math.PI/180 * degrees;
  return result;
}   
</script>
</html>
```